# Android Text-to-speech and Speech recognition at the same time

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, simultaneous

Just want to find out if we can use Text-to-speech and Speech recognition at the same time.
My use case: When the Text-to-speech is speaking something if the user says "stop" then the tts should stop reading.

I am using `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` for Text to Speech and `android.speech.SpeechRecognizer` for Speech recognition.
Both work fine when tested independently but when used at the same time, the speech recognizer is not working.

Am I missing something fundamental here? When the text to speech is in progress can we get hold of the microphone?

Comment: Now consider another scenario, when your `TextToSpeech` reads __STOP__ from text and it says ___STOP___

Comment: Thats my fundamental doubt: can we make the voice recognizer to ignore the speech coming from the phone and only consider the external sources?

Comment: Yeah, I think even if it is possible, it is no good idea, because the words from the human will be disturbed by the words of the tts. You will possibly get no good results. This is not a programming language problem, this would be a physical problem. There is also no api dependent solution to ignore tts

Comment: The voice recorded in `TextToSpeech` is also from a human. You might need to write a speech recognizer, which stores and can identify voice of a particular person. That's more like writing a software for safe, which only opens on voice command from master.

Comment: If nothing else - humans are physically incapable of speaking while listening to speech.